# Kohana-v3 ORM parent relationship

Tags: php, orm, kohana, foreign-key-relationship, kohana-3

I just started with the version 3 of the Kohana Framework.
I have worked a little with the $_has_many etc.

Now I have the table pages. The primary key is pageID. The table has a column called parentPageID. Now I want to make a ORM model who, when accesed like this `$page->parent->find()` returns the page identified by parentPageID.

I have the following already:

```
// Settings
protected $_table_name  = 'pages';
protected $_primary_key = 'pageID';
protected $_has_one = array(
    'parent' => array(
        'model'     => 'page',
        'foreign_key'   => 'parentPageID',
    ),
);
```

But that does not work, it simply returns the first page from the table. Last query says this:

```
SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` ORDER BY `pages`.`pageID` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Does somebody know how to solve this?

I know this can: `$parent = $page->parent->find($page->parentPageID);` but it must be and can be cleaner (I think).

**Solved**, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it my self. I needed to swap the things. I explain:

You can make a sentence like this: A page belongs to his parent page.

So, when I thought like that I know what i did wrong.

No I have this (what works perfectly):

```
protected $_belongs_to = array
(
    'parent' => array
    (
        'model' => 'page',
        'foreign_key' => 'parentPageID'
    )
);
protected $_has_many = array
(
    'childs' => array
    (
        'model' => 'page',
        'foreign_key' => 'parentPageID',
    )
);
```

I can use it like this:

```
$havesParent = $page->parent->loaded();
$childs = $page->childs->find_all()->as_array();
// ...
```

@Stackoverflow
Sorry I filled your database with a question I answered my self.